# How to implement Error Logging in Windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

Hi I am developing an windows phone  application.

I want to implement error logging in my app. I want to handle error logs in better way.

- How can log the error information(so that it will be helpful for the developer to rectify the error)
- Are there any 3rd party tools / free library's for error logging in metro apps.
- What are the various alternatives available for error logging?
- What is the best followed practice for error logging?

Please help me out.

Your answer will be very helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a rather vague and open-ended question. The answers you need are probably specific to you dependent on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

1) Some times I just save the Exception.ToString() in a local database and when the WP has internet conection I sent that data.

2, 3 & 4) [mtiks](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810133) offers an easy to implement real-time Mobile App Analytics for major mobile platforms which include Windows Phone. App publishers can integrate the framework within minutes to understand their app usage using different reports and charts. Features include Error Tracking, Events, Events with Attributes, etc. Additionally, mtiks offers a companion app for Windows Phone to monitor activity

Comment: Just in case, according the their home page the [mtiks](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810133) service is shutting down by Dec 31, 2014.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, some of the errors that can cause application problems are logged through the dev center, so when you publish your app, you will get reports that show you what exceptions happened that caused crashes.

In normal conditions, you could have a web service running on your end, that would receive information about non-critical exceptions as those occur (work around the fact that the phone might not always be connected to a network - serialize the exception stack trace and send it when connected, as shown in the other answer).

For error logging, there is a project called [WPClogger](http://wpclogger.codeplex.com/). For more serious reports and analytics, there is [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/).

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any 3rd party tools / free library's for error logging in metro apps.

For the start - check out the free [MetroLog](https://github.com/mbrit/metrolog) library.

> What are the various alternatives available for error logging?

If you feel that you are ready for something more about logging, I could recommend the [Sentry](https://getsentry.com) service. They have free "Trial" subscription plan with 7 day history and 250 events per day limit - this may be enough for personal "pet" projects and good start option for any mature app. Although they do have [.NET client library](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-csharp), last time I've checked it I end up with a few minor modifications in this library source code to make it compilable for Windows Store/Phone apps (like namespace renames or something trivial like that), but things may be better now days.